# Global uncaught exception handler -> email log to me?

Tags: android

Is there any way to catch crashes in my own android app? Something like a global uncaught exception handler? Just wondering if I could install something like that, then if an uncaught exception is thrown, I could pop up a dialog for the user and ask if they want to mail a dump of the exception to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

> Is there any way to catch crashes in
>   my own android app? Something like a
>   global uncaught exception handler?

See `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`.

> Just wondering if I could install
>   something like that, then if an
>   uncaught exception is thrown, I could
>   pop up a dialog for the user and ask
>   if they want to mail a dump of the
>   exception to me.

You can also use Flurry, DroidDrop, or any of the other implementations of this already available.

Comment: You may want to look at my complete solution write-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file

Answer (score 4):

[Bugsense.com](http://www.bugsense.com) also does this (for free)

Comment: From download to use in a few minutes, awesome tool!

Comment: It has restrictions on free usage. 500 reports per month.

Answer (score 3):

[Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) does this, plus a lot of other useful things.

Answer (score 0):

DroidDrop is a dead project. Neat Idea though wish they open sourced it.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, we've been using [Crittercism's free plan](http://www.crittercism.com/features.html) with success. They also offer some premium features, like handling the exception so the app doesn't crash.

In the free version, the user still sees the crash, but at least I get the email and the stack trace.

We also use the iOS version (but I've heard from my colleagues that it is not quite as good).

---

Here are similar questions:

- [Is it possible to create some sort of global exception handler in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904684/is-it-possible-to-create-some-sort-of-global-exception-handler-in-android)
- [Ideal way to set global uncaught exception Handler in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764394/ideal-way-to-set-global-uncaught-exception-handler-in-android)