# Android return to a previous Activity if another Activity crashes

Tags: android, exception, android-activity

Is there a way to ask Android to return to a previous `Activity` within my application in the event that another `Activity` causes an unhandled exception to be thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use [`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) to receive notification when any thread has died due to an unhandled exception. But I'm not sure about Dalvik implementation of that mechanism. It could be possible you would not be able to start another activity from the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` as the documentation says nothing about thread/process resurrection.

**Update**

Ok. I tested it and now I'm sure you will **NOT** be able to return to a previous Activity using the above technique if your application thrown an exception in the UI thread. This happens because that exception would cause application [main looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper%28%29) to exit and thus your application would not be able to process any further UI messages.

The only possible way I've found to achieve what you want is the following dirty-hack:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    while (true) {
      try {
        Log.i("MyLooper", "Starting my looper");
        Looper.loop();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyLooper", "Caught the exception in UI thread, e:", e);
        showPreviousActivity();
      }
    }
  }

  private void showPreviousActivity() {
    // your implementation of showing the previous activity
  }   
}
```

And register MyApplication in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication">
…
```

The implementation of the `showPreviousActivity()` method is up to you. One of the possible solution would be to keep track of the currently Activity instance in some ActivityTracker class and to call current activity `finish()` method from the `showPreviousActivity` code.

Comment: If the application has more than 1 `Activity` running, `getApplicationContext()` will still provide a valid `Context`.  You can then call `startActivity()` from inside a registered `UncaughtExceptionHandler` ;)

Comment: If you use `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and exception happens in the UI thread then `startActivity()` won't help since main looper would be already dead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `try-catch` block to catch the exception and `startActivity` there. You can not go to another activity without catching it.

Comment: There is no exception, atm. I would like to code in the event that I have an unhandled exception, I don't know where it is going to be.

Comment: you need to figure it out as when activity crashes, it will close the app.

Comment: It is a hypothetical scenario, as it is not crashing at the moment

Comment: then the answer is NO. When the activity crashes you are out of control and you are left with no choice except to restart the app....