# App closing event in Android

Tags: android, performance

Is there any way to know your application is running ? 
I want to run a piece of code when Android app is just closed. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: try do your code in onDestroy() in master activity...

Comment: I have tried in onDestroy. but there is no such a event call when I close app from launcher's menu.

Comment: Yes you can check what are the app is running on your device, it gives the package identifier name of those apps.

Comment: Ya you can identify it, but I think first implement onDestroy() method. Then also can you please tell me what's your exact requirements?

Comment: I m working on the app. It should be hit the web service just before closing the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to answer my own question now after so much time. When user close the app, the process is terminated with no notice. onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called. only when you explicitly call finish().

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to make a custom application class and note store the visibility of application wether it is running in background or not.obviously if you don't close the application like this

[How to close Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application)

have a look at this so that you don't close it from background and perform the visibility check like this.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
return activityVisible;
}  

public static void activityResumed() {
activityVisible = true;
}

public static void activityPaused() {
activityVisible = false;
}

 private static boolean activityVisible;
}
```

and this is how you register you application class to the manifest file.

```
<application
android:name="your.app.package.MyApplication"
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

and override these two methods like this.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
MyApplication.activityResumed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
MyApplication.activityPaused();
}
```

now check this status and perform what you like if it is running in background.You can take help of Booleans to check if the application is not closed by other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

In general, there's no such thing as closing applications in Android: the user just stops using the app. It's up to the programmer to make sure that the user does not mention process creation and termination.

Please note that Android may kill the application process when it lacks memory and restart the application later.

For example, one of old office-like apps had the following bug: the user wanted to insert a photo, the office application invoked the Camera app, and Android killed the office app. The office app was not ready for a restart and lost all document changes (which was the bug). Apparently, the buggy app ignored the bundle passed to onCreate().

So the process life cycle and the application life cycle are different things. The process restart *is* visible to the application: the static variables get reset to their initial values (most likely, null). So it is possible to have a non-null bundle and null static data structures.

One example of executing a piece of code when the process dies may be found below:
[Android camera locked after force close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318637/android-camera-locked-after-force-close/17336974#17336974) .
The problem solved in that post was that Android by itself does not close the camera when the process dies. I cannot tell from your post whether or not your problem is similar to this one.

Comment: Is there any way to check app is running through service. let suppose we start a service on app launch and the service continuously check app is running or not.

Comment: You may create your service in a separate process by specifying in AndroidManifest.xml `<service ... android:process=":someName" ... </service>`

Comment: But you cannot know which process will be killed first.

Answer (score 1):

If you uses, in your Activity, an object derivated from the class: ViewModel, you can capture the event: onCleared(); which is called always, after onDestroy().
See: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel