# customize run time error message

Tags: android, runtime, customization, message

when there is a run time error in my application it shows error dialog box with message,

The application [app name] (process com.[package name] has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

This message is OK but the problem is it is showing the package name.  The package name contain our company name. I don't want to show it with the error message.

Is there a way to customize this message?

Answer (score 1):

This is a system message and not customizable by any specific app.  This message shows up when  your application crashes.  I would suggest addressing the root cause of the problem and finding out when and why your app is crashing.  Then you can prevent this message altogether.

You can also add global, application level exception handling as detailed in this post:
[Ideal way to set global uncaught exception Handler in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764394/ideal-way-to-set-global-uncaught-exception-handler-in-android)

Comment: we are doing everything we can to prevent errors. But that does not mean there will never be an error. We are wondering whether we can modify the message ...

Comment: @Janaka It is a valid question and I didn't mean to imply that it wasn't.  You can't change the message but maybe something like this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764394/ideal-way-to-set-global-uncaught-exception-handler-in-android (I updated my answer with this info too)