# Viewing logcat in tablet

Tags: android, debugging

Is there a way to view the log on a tablet running 4.4?  I've downloaded several apps like aLogCat and none of them show what my app writes out with S.o.p or Log.d.  I have an intermittent bug that gives the Unfortunately appname has stopped message.Is there any way to view the log after this event without having to connect to a PC and use the adb program?
What other ways are there to get debug output?  Would trapping the System.out and System.err classes get the stack trace?

Thanks,
Norm

Answer (score 1):

You're focussing on tring to read out logcat, but there are better solutions for reading crash logs. My personal preference is [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/), which automatically logs fatal exceptions and provides mechanisms for logging other messages.

The way all these crash reporters work, is by defining a UncaughtExceptionHandler:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler(this));
```

If you prefer to use your own solution, you may want to look into using this. [See this related question for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764394/ideal-way-to-set-global-uncaught-exception-handler-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to view the log on a tablet running 4.4?

No, sorry. An app can only see its own log messages, not those from other apps. Hence, a third-party log viewer cannot see your app's messages.

> Is there any way to view the log after this event without having to connect to a PC and use the adb program?

Use any standard crash management library, like [ACRA](http://acra.ch/), or services like Crashlytics, BugSense, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The AIDE Application (Android Integrated Development Environment) allows one to develop android Apps directly on android device.

One particular feature is to read the logcat.

You can get it here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui

Comment: Does AIDE require that it be used to develop the app?  I'd rather develop on a PC with a full sized monitor.

Comment: My bad, I just checked again AIDE and the logs are only on the app that has been installed with it :(. I am as disapointed as you are. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I've put in the program.  It seems to work:

```
    // Define inner class to handle exceptions
    class MyExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e){
           java.util.Date dt =  new java.util.Date();
           String fn = LogFilePathPfx + "exception_" + sdf.format(dt) + ".txt";
           try{ 
              PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( fn );
              e.printStackTrace(ps);
              ps.close();
              System.out.println("wrote trace to " + fn);
              e.printStackTrace(); // capture here also???
              SaveStdOutput.stop(); // close here vs calling flush() in class 
           }catch(Exception x){
              x.printStackTrace();
           }
           lastUEH.uncaughtException(t, e); // call last one  Gives: "Unfortunately ... stopped" message
           return;    //???? what to do here
        }
     }

     lastUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(); // save previous one
     Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler());
```