# Is an uncaught exception always the cause of a crashing app

Tags: java, android, exception

Asking a very generic question, and it seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978245/how-to-prevent-android-app-from-crashing-due-to-exception-in-background-thread) is the same problem asked from the other side. But I'm wondering if there is any other reason, other than an uncaught exception, can make an Android app crash?

That is, is it true that if I were to have a big try catch surrounding every thread, there would always be a chance to do some cleanup right before things blow up?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a **crash**? A deadlock could be considered a crash and would not throw an `Exception`.

Comment: Ah I meant that "Unfortunately xxx has stopped" dialog box.

Comment: It may be caused by an Error. For example IOError