# "Unfortunately, myapp has stopped" - change message?

Tags: android

My app crashes due to a runtime exception - I know what is causing it, so I can catch the exception. However, I don't really mind if the app closes (the reason behind the crash is pretty cut and dry)... I just want to be able to tell the user why it crashed.

Is it possible to change that error message?

Answer (score 2):

You should catch the exception and show your own dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** show some excpetions, but if it's a `RuntimeException` the app will crash inevitably. You need to do a little tweak to handle exceptions differently. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978245/how-to-prevent-android-app-from-crashing-due-to-exception-in-background-thread).