# it's possible to change message when Android application is unfortunately apps has stopped?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have not any idea about for this.
This message is changes or not in android application. I want to make that custom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you can't change it.

Comment: If the application has stopped responding, how would the application change the message?

Comment: You can't change the message.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764394/ideal-way-to-set-global-uncaught-exception-handler-in-android) will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and assign it to your *Application*.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CrashHandler());
    }
}

public final class CrashHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private final UncaughtExceptionHandler handler;

    public CrashHandler() {
        // Uncomment this line if you want to show the default app crash message
        //this.handler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(final Thread thread, final Throwable throwable) {
        // Show pretty message to user

        // Uncomment this line to show the default app crash message
        //this.handler.uncaughtException(thread, throwable);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to set custom message in it?

Comment: I think this will do it.                                                                                `throw new RuntimeException("Custom Message");`

Comment: How to assign MyApplication class to project?

Comment: @KrishnaChandran using throw new RuntimeException("Custom Message"); it didnt worked!