# logcat not showing debugging messages

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

**logcat** in Android Studio is not showing my generated outputs via `Log.v/.d` or any stacktraces after an unhandled runtime exception (like a nullpointer) and no further information when the app crashes. `Log.i/.w/.wtf/.e` messages are sometimes shown. Also `selfgenerated` messages from Android classes are shown (only sometimes!) and Android system outputs(normally always shown in logcat).

logcat filter settings are on "verbose" and "no filter" or "show only selected application" (both not solving my problem). Nothing entered in the searchmask. Restarting didn't solve the problem.

I tried out different smartphones and emulators with Android 5.1/6 and several projects/apps.

Example code (only more important messages than debug are shown):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Log.v(TAG, "verbose test");
    Log.d(TAG, "debug test");
    Log.i(TAG, "info test");
    Log.w(TAG, "warn test");
    Log.wtf(TAG, "what a terrible failure test");
    Log.e(TAG, "error test");
}
```

Edit: logcat output for the code above (with "verbose" & "show only selected applictaion" filter options):

```
12-02 22:01:13.531 14717-14717/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni

12-02 22:01:13.593 14717-14730/de.kinoblub.testapp E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc

12-02 22:01:13.621 14717-14717/de.kinoblub.testapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/de.kinoblub.testapp-1/lib/arm64

12-02 22:01:13.624 14717-14717/de.kinoblub.testapp I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is de.kinoblub.testapp, real application class is null.

12-02 22:01:13.717 14717-14717/de.kinoblub.testapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/de.kinoblub.testapp-1/lib/arm64

12-02 22:01:13.837 14717-14717/de.kinoblub.testapp I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl

12-02 22:01:13.883 14717-14717/de.kinoblub.testapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

12-02 22:01:14.031 14717-14717/de.kinoblub.testapp I/de.kinoblub.testapp.Main2Activity: info test

12-02 22:01:14.031 14717-14717/de.kinoblub.testapp W/de.kinoblub.testapp.Main2Activity: warn test

12-02 22:01:14.031 14717-14717/de.kinoblub.testapp E/de.kinoblub.testapp.Main2Activity: what a terrible failure test

12-02 22:01:14.044 14717-14717/de.kinoblub.testapp E/de.kinoblub.testapp.Main2Activity: error test

12-02 22:01:14.067 14717-14717/de.kinoblub.testapp I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null

12-02 22:01:14.167 14717-14747/de.kinoblub.testapp E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc

12-02 22:01:14.167 14717-14747/de.kinoblub.testapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

12-02 22:01:14.235 14717-14717/de.kinoblub.testapp I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
```

Comment: Are you using a Huawei device?

Answer (score 2):

This happens quite often, change logcat filter settings to "verbose" and "show only selected application", this works for me, I hope it works for you too.

Comment: "Verbose" is selected, "show only selected application" also not working.

Comment: Try Invalidate Cache and restart , then put logcat settings to "verbose" and "show only selected application".

Comment: Done. Didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

It's common problem.
Check that you have connected right device, you are debugging right process, clear filter bar.

Answer (score 0):

Is the same problems observed if you are debugging your app on emulator or some other device? If not, you may need to change the device's logging output level. Which is somehow lowered while you are actually debugging the app by Android Studio, but then reset to default phone's level once it's crashed.

Another fix would be to start using some log4j based logger (e.g. [logback](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android)) and config it to write logs to file at your desired level. You can also catch [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764394/ideal-way-to-set-global-uncaught-exception-handler-in-android?rq=1) and send logs to email or server if app crashes (on next app's start).