# How to release Android resources when an app crashes

Tags: android, crash, finalize, audiorecord

I'm working an Android AudioRecord app.  If I do not call the `release()` method on the AudioRecord object at the end of the script, it will not run correctly until I restart the phone.

This becomes a major hassle when working on this project because if the app should ever crash (which happens sometimes while testing and there's an unexpected buffer overflow, etc.) then I have to restart the phone every time.

I have the method to release the buffers inside the `finalize()` method of my AudioListener class, and I also call them `onStop()` of the main Activity.

Neither of these seem to work when the app freezes or crashes.  Is there a way to attach the release action to an error handler or some general way of ensuring that an app will execute some code to release resources properly even after a crash.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This will probably help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654168/global-uncaught-exception-handler-email-log-to-me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own Application class (need to be declared in AndroidManifest.xml) and then overwrite methods:

```
Application.onLowMemory();
Application.onTerminate();
```

More about it can be read in Android manuals for `Application`

Comment: Application.onTerminate() is for use in emulated process environments and not in production.

Comment: Yes, I too agree with @MuhammadMuzammil. Not sure why this question is marked as answered. onTerminate is not reliable and won't work in device.