# Generate log file on app crash android

Tags: android

I am working on a project which will not be published in google play. My client is running it on beta. They says it crashes sometimes, but I was never able to reproduce the scenarios.

So I just want to generate a LOG file when the app crashes. Is it possible to get such events?

i.e When the app forces to close I need to generate a log file with the last few actions ( logcat items) .

Comment: ya this is better way you generate the log file

Comment: Install aLogcat application, from this you will get all application log

Comment: You may want to look at my complete solution write-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file

Answer (score 3):

You can tell your client to install aLogcat ,using this he can get the log of your app

Here is the link [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en)

Answer (score 3):

Following is the code which allows you to generate a log file from "logs".

```
try {
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

  StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     log.append(line);
  }
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    //handle exception
}
```

Permission you need to take is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register UncaughtExceptionHandler for your application and log unexpected crashes to file.

Check this out, [Global uncaught exception handler -> email log to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654168/global-uncaught-exception-handler-email-log-to-me?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

use crittercism library  [crittercism crash reporting](https://www.crittercism.com/signup/)

this sends crash logs on your registered account  and you can register email id's on which you want crash logs

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to log error to a the phone's storage device I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36910473/5675550) which refers to a tutorial [here](https://doandroid.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/writing-crash-reports-into-device-sd-card/)