# How to programmatically get android logs from a release build

Tags: android, logging

I've seen plenty of ways of getting **system** logs in Android with logcat and the like, but not so much about app logs (except for the usual USB + `adb` solution).

My B2B Android app produces useful logging created with `Log.i` calls. Whilst in Studio these are very useful for debugging, it would also be useful to get these from customer's installs when things go wrong, i.e. from a release build out in the wild. Customers are generally not techies so getting logs via `adb` isn't really an option.

**Is there a way within the app code itself to grab all the log contents?**

Perhaps the SDK provides a way to do this?

I could then send that to my server or by email. I'm thinking it'll be useful for my customers to just hit a button so I can get an instantaneous snapshot of what is happening in the app.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this, aside from writing to a file and sending that file. Which I guess is a good a solution as any.

Two other interesting ones that have come up are:

- Firebase (from Mohammed's comment) - can log events:https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events
- Instabug

Comment: There is no documented and supported means of doing this. You will find undocumented and unsupported solutions that run the `logcat` command on the device. You may be better served logging this information to some file that you control.

Comment: i am not sure but did you try crashlytics? or firebase?

Comment: @MohammedAtif both crashlytics and firebase give you crash reports, but  they only give stack traces plus some other info. I need to have logs in the non-crashing case too. Instabug looks good, but it's not free

Comment: @MohammedAtif actually there is event logging with firebase, so that's a possibility - https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events

Answer (score 0):

we can write write logs to file using java.util.logging.Logger API.

[How to write logs in text file when using java.util.logging.Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758685/how-to-write-logs-in-text-file-when-using-java-util-logging-logger)

Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36910473/4247543) for writting crash log to a file